# Import GData library for use with Google App Engine

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, eclipse-plugin

I'm having hard time trying to figure out how to import a Gdata library into my eclipse build to use with Google App Engine(Java)

Answer (score 1):

just put the gdata jar in the application WEB-INF/lib jar file

Have you added below in appengine-web.xml

```
<system-properties>
  <property name="com.google.gdata.DisableCookieHandler" value="true"/>
 </system-properties>
```

You can refer to http://code.google.com/appengine/kb/java.html#googledata

Comment: Thanks for the speedy reply. I've tried this approach though. I placed all of the Gdata files in the WEB-INF/lib folder in my eclipse directory. I deployed it and whenever I tried to call the servlet via http the web browser(chrome) it gives me a 500 error. 

I am using the com.google.gdata.client.spreadsheet.SpreadsheetService package.

Comment: Yes I have including this as well and still I get this error - 

Error: Server Error

The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.
If the problem persists, please report your problem and mention this error message and the query that caused it.